# Find Max value of this expression: $P=(x-2yz)(y-2zx)(z-2xy)$

Tags: inequality

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positives and satisfying $x^2+y^2+z^2=2xyz+1$ .

Find a maximum of this expression:
$$P=(x-2yz)(y-2zx)(z-2xy).$$

Comment: Try to use Lagrange Multiplier technique.

Comment: Did you mean find the maximum?

Comment: @user2345215: Yep , maximum. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Set $y=x$ and $z=1$. Then $x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2+1=2xyz+1$ and
$$(x-2yz)(y-2zx)(z-2xy)=(-x)(-x)(1-2x^2)=x^2(1-2x^2)$$
which clearly has no minimum...

Comment: Yep . Sorry. You're right.  I edited my question. Find Max ... . 
Thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

.......................

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=1$ and $y=z=\frac{1}{2}.$

Hence, $P=\frac{1}{8}$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

If $x\leq2yz$ then we obtain:
$$2xy\geq2xz\geq2yz\geq x\geq y\geq z,$$
which says that $P\leq0$.

Thus, we can assume that $x>2yz$.

1. $x=1$.

In this case the condition gives $y=z$ and 
$$P=(1-2z^2)z^2=\frac{1}{2}(1-2z^2)2z^2\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-2z^2+2z^2}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{8};$$
2. $x\in(0,1).$

Let $x=\cos\alpha$.

We have here $$(x-2yz)(y-2xz)(z-2xy)=(x-2yz)(yz-2x(y^2+z^2)+4x^2yz)=$$
$$=(x-2yz)(yz-2x(1+2xyz-x^2)+4x^2yz)=(x-2yz)(2x^3-2x+yz)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(x-2yz)(4x^3-4x+2yz)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-2yz+4x^3-4x+2yz}{2}\right)^2=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}(4x^3-3x)^2=\frac{1}{8}\cos^23\alpha\leq\frac{1}{8}.$$
3. $x>1$.

In this case we obtain:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-1-2xyz\geq x^2+2yz-1-2xyz=(x-1)(x-2yz+1)>0,$$
which is a contradiction and this case is just impossible.

Done!